# WSL: No network whatsoever

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have WSL2 and it was working fine, then seemingly overnight it has no network access. `ifconfig` returns nothing (blank line)

I have now uninstalled and reinstalled it (20.04) and I have the same problem. I also tried installing Debian which also has no network.

I have tried running this that I found on a help thread, but it doesn't work:

```
wsl --shutdown
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh winsock reset
shutdown /r
```

Comment: Thanks for moving the question over here from Ask Ubuntu.  Is there any chance that part of the Windows drive is compressed or encrypted?  Compression of the Windows temp directory is known to cause WSL internet issues.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Please note that the question is asking about WSL.  Your wording ("adapter", "format", "hardware", etc.) makes me believe that you are referring to a full Linux installation on a computer.  Since the OP doesn't indicate that the Windows networking has any problem, it's unlikely to be a hardware issue.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds There was compression on the file. I had to disable encryption on the file in appdata/local/Packages to get the reinstall to boot.

Comment: Is anything else compressed or encrypted?  As much as you can turn off compression and encryption, I'd recommend doing so for troubleshooting this.  You can always try re-enabling them when (hopefully) you resolve.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4275#issuecomment-695068842) on a related Github issue on WSL.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, you are right, totally misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @NotTheDr01ds. So, decompressing the appdata/local/packages entry was not enough, but when I decompressed the whole user directory, the networking works again.

Comment: Sorry, never saw the response on this (don't get notified of @tag's in answers, just comments).  Just happened to find this when Googling for a related problem for someone else.  In retrospect, yes, I'm guessing it was compression of the `temp` directory.  But perhaps another one.  Good to hear you got it working.